# Non-integer degree of Hermite polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

**SYSTEM**

I have a system of differential equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} (\sigma^x)^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_- (x_t)}{\partial x_t^2} + \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) \frac{\partial V_- (x_t)}{\partial x_t} - e_- V_- (x_t) &= -\frac{+ 2x_t - 2 \lambda e_+ (a_0 + a_1 x_t)}{e_- - e_+} \\
\frac{1}{2} (\sigma^x)^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_+ (x_t)}{\partial x_t^2} + \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) \frac{\partial V_+ (x_t)}{\partial x_t} - e_+ V_+ (x_t) &= -\frac{- 2x_t + 2 \lambda e_- (a_0 + a_1 x_t)}{e_- - e_+} 
\end{align}

**GENERAL SOLUTION HOMOGENEOUS**

To solve it, I start by finding the general solution of the homogeneous equations (I condense the two solutions into one by using the symbol $\pm$):
\begin{align}
V_\mp^g(x_t) = c_\mp^1 H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x }\right) + c_\mp^2 \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t -a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2}\right)
\end{align}
where $H_n(x_t)$ is the Hermite function (i.e. the generalization of the $n$-th physicist's Hermite polynomial):
\begin{align}
H_n(x_t) = 2^n \sqrt{\pi} \left( \frac{1}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1-n}{2} \right)} \, _1F_1 \left( - \frac{n}{2}; \frac{1}{2}; x_t^2 \right) - \frac{2x_t}{\Gamma \left( -\frac{n}{2} \right)} \, _1F_1 \left( \frac{1-n}{2}; \frac{3}{2}; x_t^2 \right) \right)
\end{align}
and $_1F_1(a,b,x_t)$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function:
\begin{align}
_1F_1(a,b,x_t) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a)} x_t^k}{\frac{\Gamma(b+k)}{\Gamma(b)}  k!} 
\end{align}

**PARTICULAR SOLUTION INHOMOGENEOUS**

Then I find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation with the variation of parameters method:
\begin{align}
V_\mp^p(x_t) = - v_\mp^{g1}(x_t) \int \frac{v_\mp^{g2}(x_t) f_\mp(x_t)}{a_\mp(x_t) w_\mp(x_t)} dx + v_\mp^{g2}(x_t) \int \frac{v_\mp^{g1}(x_t) f_\mp(x_t)}{a_\mp(x_t) w_\mp(x_t)} dx 
\end{align}
where $w_\mp(x_t)$ is the Wronskian:
\begin{align}
w_\mp(x_t) = v_\mp^{g1}(x_t)\frac{\partial v_\mp^{g2}(x_t)}{\partial x_t} - v_\mp^{g2}(x_t) \frac{\partial v_\mp^{g1}(x_t)}{\partial x_t}
\end{align}
and where:
\begin{align}
v_\pm^{g1} = H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x }\right)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
v_\pm^{g2} = _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t -a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2}\right)
\end{align}

**GENERAL SOLUTION INHOMOGENEOUS**

Third, the general solution to the nonhomogeneous equation is equal to the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation and the particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation:
\begin{align}
V_\mp(x_t) &= c_\mp^1 H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right)+c_\mp^2 \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right) \mp \\
& \mp H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right) \frac{2 a_1^2}{e_\mp (e_--e_+)} \times \nonumber \\
& \times \int \frac{ (e_\pm \lambda  (a_0+a_1 x_t)-x_t) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right) }{\left(a_1^2 x_t - a_0 \delta\right) H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1}+1;\frac{3}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right) +a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x H_{-\frac{a_1+e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right)} \, dx_t \pm \nonumber \\
&\pm \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right) \frac{2 a_1^2}{e_\mp (e_--e_+)} \times \nonumber \\
& \times \int \frac{ (e_\pm \lambda  (a_0+a_1 x_t)-x_t) H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right)}{\left(a_1^2 x_t - a_0 \delta\right) H_{-\frac{e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1}+1;\frac{3}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right) + a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x H_{-\frac{a_1+e_\mp}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sigma^x}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_\mp}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 (\sigma^x)^2 }\right)} \, dx_t \nonumber 
\end{align}
It follows that:
\begin{align}
\textbf{J}(x_t) &= \textbf{Q} \textbf{V}(x_t) \\
\begin{bmatrix}
J_{x_t}(x_t) \\
J_{\pi_t}(x_t)
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
e_- V_-(x_t) + e_+ V_+(x_t) \\
V_-(x_t) + V_+(x_t) \\
\end{bmatrix} \nonumber \\
\begin{bmatrix}
J_{x_t}(x_t) \\
J_{\pi_t}(x_t)
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
e_- (V_-^g(x_t) + V_-^p(x_t)) + e_+ (V_+^g(x_t) + V_+^p(x_t)) \\
V_-^g(x_t) + V_-^p(x_t) + V_+^g(x_t) + V_+^p(x_t) \\
\end{bmatrix} \nonumber \\
\begin{bmatrix}
J_{x_t}(x_t) \\
J_{\pi_t}(x_t)
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
e_- (c_-^1 v_-^{g1}(x_t) + c_-^2 v_-^{g2}(x_t) + V_-^p(x_t) ) + e_+ ( c_+^1 v_+^{g1}(x_t) + c_+^2 v_+^{g2}(x_t) + V_+^p(x_t) )\\
c_-^1 v_-^{g1}(x_t) + c_-^2 v_-^{g2}(x_t) + V_-^p(x_t) + c_+^1 v_+^{g1}(x_t) + c_+^2 v_+^{g2}(x_t) + V_+^p(x_t) \nonumber
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
e_\pm = \frac{\delta \theta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \theta^2 + 4 \theta (\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)}}{2 \theta} \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \frac{- \delta \theta + \sqrt{\delta^2 \theta^2 + 4 \theta (\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)}}{2 \theta}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
V = Q^{-1} J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
V_- \\
V_+
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
Q^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e_- &e_+ \\
1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $J$ is the value function of an optimization problem.

**BOUNDARY CONDITIONS**

Next, I impose boundary conditions to find the four constants of $V_\mp(x_t)$ and hence the full solution of $J_{x_t}(x_t)$ and $J_{\pi_t}(x_t)$.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x_t \to \hat{x}^+} J_{x_t}(x_t) &= 0 \\
e_- (c_-^1 v_-^{g1}(\hat{x}) + c_-^2 v_-^{g2}(\hat{x}) + V_-^p(\hat{x}) ) + e_+ ( c_+^1 v_+^{g1}(\hat{x}) + c_+^2 v_+^{g2}(\hat{x}) + V_+^p(\hat{x}) ) &= 0 \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\lim_{x_t \to \hat{x}^+} J_{x_t x_t}(x_t) &= 0 \\
e_- \left(c_-^1 \frac{\partial v_-^{g1}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + c_-^2 \frac{\partial v_-^{g2}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + \frac{\partial V_-^p(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} \right) + e_+ \left( c_+^1 \frac{\partial v_+^{g1}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + c_+^2 \frac{\partial v_+^{g2}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + {\partial V_+^p(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} \right) &= 0 \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\lim_{x_t \to \hat{x}^+} J_{\pi_t}(x_t) &= \frac{2 \theta}{(\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)} x_t \\
c_-^1 v_-^{g1}(\hat{x}) + c_-^2 v_-^{g2}(\hat{x}) + V_-^p(\hat{x}) + c_+^1 v_+^{g1}(\hat{x}) + c_+^2 v_+^{g2}(\hat{x}) + V_+^p(\hat{x}) &= \frac{2 \theta}{(\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)} \hat{x} \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\lim_{x_t \to \hat{x}^+} J_{\pi_t x_t}(x_t) &= \frac{2 \theta}{(\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)} \\
c_-^1 \frac{\partial v_-^{g1}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + c_-^2 \frac{\partial v_-^{g2}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + \frac{\partial V_-^p(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + c_+^1 \frac{\partial v_+^{g1}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + c_+^2 \frac{\partial v_+^{g2}(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} + \frac{\partial V_+^p(\hat{x})}{\partial x_t} &= \frac{2 \theta}{(\epsilon - 1) (1 + \varphi)} \nonumber
\end{align}

**QUESTION**

Notice that $-\frac{e_-}{a_1}$ is an integer but $-\frac{e_+}{a_1}$ is not. What does this imply about the validity of the solutions? Does this mean I can exclude the first term of the general solution for $V_+^g(x_t)$ because the degree of the Hermite polynomial is not an integer? I am confused because for a non-integer $n$ we can work with the Hermite function rather than the Hermite polynomial but I am not sure whether we can exclude the solution. Moreover, I does not seem to me that the boundary conditions can be satisfied only for special values of the index $n$. The reason I ask this question, is that if I were to keep the solutions as they are, I would be using all four available boundary conditions to determine the constants, and I would have no equation left to back out $\hat{x}$.

Comment: I have updated the solution to mention the boundary conditions as well. I will take a closer look but this does not seem to be the case.